# how to place controllers into modules with ngdoc

Tags: angularjs, jsdoc

I use the grunt grunt-ngdocs module and this is the the code which creates the documentation.

```
ngdocs: {
            all: app_files,
            scripts: ['angular.js']
        }
```

I have a module called starter and two controllers: controllerA, controllerB

```
/**
  * 
  * @ngdoc object
  * @name controllerA

  * @description  ...
  */

/**
  * 
  * @ngdoc object
  * @name controllerB

  * @description  ...
  */
```

When running the documentation generator these controllers are shown as modules.

How do i write it in the ngdoc markup that both of them are connected to module starter?

contollerA and controllerB are in different files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually you write ngdoc this way for controllers:

> @name moduleName.controller:ControllerName

In your case you can write:

```
/**
 * @ngdoc controller
 * @name starter.controller:controllerA
 *
 * ....
*/
```

Comment: Why is the extra `.controller:` necessary?

Comment: You can also write `@name moduleName.factory:factoryName` to document a factory. So if you build the documentation it will seperate all of them (service, directive, controller, etc.)